# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug'. > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android studio would anyone please help? I get below error randomly when I run my app. Here is my Gradle output.

I tried below links but not found proper solution for this

[Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913783/execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug)

[Execution failed for task 'app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558737/execution-failed-for-task-apppreparedebugandroidtestdependencies)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

**What went wrong:**

> Execution failed for task
>   :app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug'.
>        java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
>           Try:
>       Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

```
 Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:213)
    at com.google.common.base.Optional.of(Optional.java:85)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.incremental.InstantRunBuildContext.setVerifierResult(InstantRunBuildContext.java:69)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunVerifierTransform.doTransform(InstantRunVerifierTransform.java:142)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.InstantRunVerifierTransform.transform(InstantRunVerifierTransform.java:121)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:151)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:148)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:147)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:244)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:231)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 14 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 14.898 secs
```

Comment: `NullPointerException` post your code

Comment: I have this kind of error too, I dont know where to start to find this

Comment: Old question, but : has someone facing this problem has ever tried to clean and build project again ? It worked for me.